# How to generate URL file from cloud storage without duration in Spring

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

The following is the source code generated url from cloud storage that I made

```
public String generateImageUrl(String fileName, Integer duration, String folderName) throws IOException {

    Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new ClassPathResource(STORAGE_FILE_NAME).getInputStream());
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).setProjectId(PROJECT_ID).build().getService();
    Bucket bucket = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME, Storage.BucketGetOption.fields(Storage.BucketField.values()));
    logger.info("Bucket name : " + bucket.getName());
    String fullImagePath = folderName + "/" + fileName;
    BlobId imgId = BlobId.of(BUCKET_NAME, fullImagePath);

        if(null!=imgId) {
            Blob blob = storage.get(imgId);
            if(null!=blob && blob.exists()) {
                URL signedUrl = storage.signUrl(blob, duration, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                String imageUrl = signedUrl.toExternalForm();
                logger.info("Generated image url : " + imageUrl);
                return imageUrl;
            }
        }

        return null;
}
```

> **But the generated url has an access duration**

how to implement it so that no access duration is given ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to create a signed url with no access duration.

Cloud Storage [Signed Urls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) have a maximum expiration delay of 7 days.

> You specify an expiration time when you create the signed URL. Anyone
>   who knows the URL can access the resource until the expiration time
>   for the URL is reached or the key used to sign the URL is rotated.

Excerpt from [Java client library docs](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/index.html)

> Note that V4 Signed URLs can't have an expiration longer than 7 days.

You can also check more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl#options).